# Load con RavenDB

Tags: nosql

Estoy tratando de juntar dos documentos en ravendb para poder sacar un dato extra, lo estoy haciendo con este query:

```
from Elementos as e
load e.Usuarios as u
select {
    Elemento: e.NombreElemento,
    NombreUsuario: u.NombreUsuario
}
```

Me muestra todo sobre el documento de elementos, pero no me muestra el nombre de usuario del documento de usuarios, en que estoy fallando??

Gracias.

Comment: Can you ask in English ?

Comment: also, what is the `pl` ?  you have `as e`, did you mean `e.NombreElemento` ?

Comment: Yeah sorry, i already make corrections

Comment: Your query seems good. Maybe the document structure is wrong ?
You should have the **related document id** in the `Usuarios` property.
Learn more about related documents in this **demo**: (note: it is not an RQL example, it is a client API example, but still)  https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/related-documents/create-related-documents